# Adding a script to a cell in Google Sheets with Dialog Box

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How can I add a script to a cell in Google Scripts with a dialog box? When I try to do it now, I am getting this error:

> You do not have permission to call show (line 19).

This is because, in the script, I am trying to call:

```
var app = UiApp.createApplication(); 
var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); 
doc.show(app);
```

I know I can do this with a button on top of the cell, but I am wondering if there is a cleaner way of doing it. I want to be able to access the cell that I am clicking (ex. A1), and with a button overlayed on the sheet, am I able to get the cell? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It looks that your are trying to use a [custom function in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions). Custom functions can't open UI elements. See [Using Apps Script Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#using_apps_script_services) to learn wich services could be used on custom functions.